# oauth + php: is it possible to make code request and token request from different domains

Tags: php, oauth

Is it possible to make code request (redirect) from one domain and then to exchange it on access token from another domain?

**P.S.** either domain is added on oauth provider side.

**P.P.S.** do every oauth provider support several domains for one app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your user can start the process on one domain, and end it on another. And as soon as you have an access token, you SHOULD be free to call API endpoints from whatever machine you wish.

This is because domain has no role other than as part of your callback URL.

Basically, you are asking about the callback right? The first thing you do is not from a "domain", it is a normal HTTP request, the second a redirect to the provider, and the third is their redirect to your callback with an access token included in the URL.